# "Application tried to present modally an active controller" issue in iOs5

Tags: iphone, ios5, navigation, apple-push-notifications, modalviewcontroller

In my iPhone app, I have two views say VC1 and VC2. In VC1 I have a button to navigate to VC2. Here is the code in the button action in VC1:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if (!appDelegate.vc2) {
    appDelegate.vc2 = [[VC2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"VC2" bundle:nil];
}
[self presentModalViewController:appDelegate.vc2 animated:NO];
```

(I have to keep some status in the VC2 thats why I declared VC2 in appdelegate file)

and in VC2, for going back I used `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

When I repeat the process of going to VC2 and returning using the button action there is no issue. But I also implemented push notification in my app. So when I get a push I send nsnotification on the Ok button click of Push notification alert view and the receive notification method is written in VC1 will receive the event, to navigate to VC2.

I used the same code as in above in receive notification method for navigating to VC2.

The second time that I try to navigate to VC2 with the Ok button click of alert view I am getting the error `Application tried to present modally an active controller` and I am having this error only in iPhone 4S (iO5). But its working fine if I repeat it using the button action in VC1.

**Edit**
Adding code in detail:

In the appdelegate file, the action for Push notification alert view Ok button:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"VC1" object:nil];
```

And in the VC1 when receive notifications:

```
- (void)recieveNotification:(NSNotification *) notification{
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        if (!appDelegate.menuVC) {
            appDelegate.menuVC = [[MenuScreenVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"MenuScreenVC" bundle:nil];
        }
        [self presentModalViewController:appDelegate.menuVC animated:NO];
}
```

and button action for the button in VC1:

```
- (IBAction)viewMenuScreen:(id)sender{

            AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            if (!appDelegate.menuVC) {
                appDelegate.menuVC = [[MenuScreenVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"MenuScreenVC" bundle:nil];
            }
            [self presentModalViewController:appDelegate.menuVC animated:NO];
}
```

and in VC2:

```
- (IBAction)backToVC1:(id)sender{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Show both the code in VC1 and VC2, and please show more of the relevant code.

Comment: I have updated the question with more code.

Comment: You can find the answer from the post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074766/application-tried-to-present-modally-an-active-controller/

Comment: @SrinivasPadidala so should i use a delegate property for dismissing the view controller? I am not sure how to use it, can point what changes should I make in the above code?