# "Application tried to present modally an active controller" despite putting in various safe guards

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I receive this exceptional only occasionally (about 20% of the times) when my controller attempts to present the modal `UIImagePickerController`. I have researched this topic quite a bit on SO, and have followed the instructions of [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429014/application-tried-to-present-modally-an-active-controller) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074766/application-tried-to-present-modally-an-active-controller) on this topic about putting various safeguards.  While this was able to reduce the frequency that I have gotten this error, I still receive it and am unsure what I could do to prevent it from happening.

My set up is the following: my root controller is a Tab Bar controller, in which I then have embedded a navigation controller. Inside this navigation controller I have `TakePhoto1Controller`, and I present my `ImagePickerController` modally when someone wants to take a picture.

My code is as the following:

```
BOOL modalPresent = (BOOL)(self.presentedViewController);
    //Present the Camera UIImagePicker if no image is taken
    if (!appDelegate.imageStorageDictionary[@"picture1"]){
        if (modalPresent == NO){ //checks if the UIImagePickerController is already modally active
            if (![[self imagePickerController] isBeingDismissed]) [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
            [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];
        }
    }
```

The error I am getting is the following:

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller .'"

Comment: Would the person who downvoted this question kindly comment on how I could improve it?

Answer (score 4):

Your logic is a little bit strange to me, you are trying to dismiss imagePickerController and present the same view controller again. The error message is basically telling you imagePickerController is presented already.

Maybe you can change your logic to

```
if (![[self imagePickerController] isBeingDismissed])
{ [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO 
                          completion:^{
                               [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];
                           }];
}
else 
  [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Don't know if that's exactly what you looking for. But hope that gives you some hints.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Unfortunately with the above code every time I try to dismiss the imagerpickercontroller I get an exception. I'll tweak it around and see what else could be done.

Comment: i am sorry, that was my mistake. I edited my code, can you try that?

Comment: Thanks for updating it. I actually did change the part in the completion block the first time :) The issue is that I still seem to get the same exception error when I try to dismiss the imagePickerController.